# How to deal with nullable state properties from NgRx in Angular components using TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

I'm using **Angular 11**, **TypeScript** and **NgRx** as state management.
My app state contains a `currentProject` property which is retrieved from a backend. Hence, at initial startup the value is undefined.

```ts
export interface AppState { 
   currentProject?: Project; // <--- Note the ? to denote that at application startup there is no currentProject and hence the value can be undefined.
}
```

In the `CurrentProjectComponent` context in the app there always is a `currentProject` value in the state.

```ts
// Angular CurrentProjectComponent
....
public currentProject$!: Observable<Project>;

constructor(private store: Store<{ app: AppState >) {
    this.currentProject$ = this.store.select((s) => s.currentProject); 
}
...
```

But when I write code to select the code from the state, I end up in undesired type casting.
I either have to

- type my `currentProject$` field as `Project | undefined`, which leads to trouble when passing its value further to pipes and other components. I would end up in typing alsmost my whole domain model in `Project | undefined` which kind of defeats the point.
- add an `as Project` cast to the NgRx selector
- filter out *undefined* currentProject values by writing:
  `this.store.select((s) => s.currentProject).pipe(filter(p => !!p));`
  but this does not work either:

> TS2322: Type 'Observable<Project | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'Observable < Project >'.

The best solution I could come up with is to filter undefined values and then cast:

```
constructor(private store: Store<{ app: AppState >) {
    this.currentProject$ = this.store.select((s) => s.currentProject).pipe(filter(p => !!p)) as Observable<Project>; 
}
```

But is this really needed in order to being able to use TypeScript? This solution does not feel like TypeScript is helping here.

Comment: You could use a [user defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) with your filter: `filter((p): p is Project => !!p)`.

Comment: hello @Wuoter, did you found any idea to deal with this situation?

Comment: @dmance I ended up typing the values with `Observable<Project | undefined>`. After some thought it started to make sense, as initially there is no project yet, and the typing should indicate that.